# primeNg how to hide the datasets labels?

Tags: angular, primeng

I dont want to set the label for each of my datasets.

In their examples, they have the following

```
export class LineChartDemo {

data: any;

constructor() {
    this.data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'First Dataset',
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                label: 'Second Dataset',
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

to describe each of the bars. I dont want to do that and I wish to hide that from my chart. 
I have attached the screen when i simply do not define a dataset label.

Any thoughts how to do this cleanly?

[image]

Comment: You have to hide top labeled which are showing undefined currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `[options]` for that.

```
options = {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    };
```

and pass it to here

```
<p-chart [options]="options" type="bar" [data]="data"></p-chart>
```